# How can I login to phpmyadmin with these information?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have to quickly look into database with phpMyAdmin but I can't reach our backend developer. I have:

- server address: #.###.###.###
- id: ubuntu / pw:******
- id: root / pw:******
- phpMyAdmin id & pw

I tried my best to create new server through 'phpMyAdmin setup' with these information but I was not able to get in. Do I need more information? If I have enough information, can anyone tell me what to do with these information?

I am keep getting following error whenever I am trying to log in.

#2002 - No such file or directory — The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

What is socket and where can I find that value? I can access to ftp of the given server.

I know this looks like stupidest question ever but I know nothing about server and database :(

Comment: You mean you cannot access to `#.###.###.###/phpmyadmin` in your browser?

Comment: yes :( those information I provided is everything I have about this server and db

Comment: How about to try `sudo service apache2 restart` (if you use `apache2`) in the server?

Comment: this works!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!

Comment: `phpmyadmin` runs on HTTP server like `apache2` and `nginx`. Please give my comment a helpful flag. :)